# Cannot exit for loop es6

Tags: javascript

I am continuing my project, which is to make a tic tac toe game in codepen. The problem I am having is with the function below.
It's suppose to calculate if someone has won and it does so except for one exception. right now the ai just places its character on the next available spot and the problem comes if I place my characters on a straight line (such as the middle line) so that I should win the computer would win in the next turn, my code always returns that the computer won.

I know this might be hard to understand as I'm just taking my own approach with the game. I have made console logs that show me that winning block is reached but then I believe the loop keeps running. I don't if this has to do with es6 and block scope but I can't get the right action to occur for this case. Most other cases I have tried seem to work correctly.

Here is the link to the codepen for full context:

[CLICK ME.](http://codepen.io/skyship/pen/WxbYXz)

EDIT:  I accidentally cut the function from the project and the pen stopped working so I fixed that. could it be that a function isn't finishing before calling another? The reason I ask is because the call to the check should not return true for the computer winning at all. That is why i am confused.

```js
    hasWon(){
      let scores = this.scoring();
      allScores: {
        for(let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
          let win = $('.end');

          let currentScore = scores[i];
          console.log("The scores here: " + scores);
          console.log("the current score: " + currentScore);
          console.log("the player score: " + (this.player * 3));
          console.log("the truth: " + (currentScore === (this.player * 3)));
        
          if(currentScore === (this.player * 3)){
            console.log("we got in here but this line isn't counting");
            win.html("<h4>Player won the Game!</h4>");
            this.hasWonEnd();
            break allScores;
          } else if (currentScore === (this.computer * 3)) {
            console.log("we are displaying this line.....");
            win.html("<h4>Computer won the Game!</h4>");
            this.hasWonEnd();
            break allScores;
          } else if (this.emptyIndices().length === 0 && i === (scores.length - 1)){
            win.html("<h4>It's a draw!</h4>");
            this.hasWonEnd();
            break allScores;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I believe it is es6 unrelated. (don't know if I should change the title.)

The call the function that detects a winner was being called after a winner had already been decided thereby overwriting it. My solution was to create game state variable that would check if there was a winner already.
I still however do not understand why the functions wouldn't complete before taking on a new value. but it is done and it seems to work fine. 
Thanks to everyone who looked at it.